# How to apply angular filter to an array

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to apply Angular  filter to the following array after following the instructions here http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:filter:

```
[{"id":"compute-1.amazonaws.com_Delivery","id":"compute-1.amazonaws.com_TaskJob","id":"UpdateFiles","id":"TaskRequest"}]
```

Say the filter values are:

```
  filter = "TaskRequest";


  filter = "Taskjob";


  filter = "UpdateFiles";


  filter = "Delivery";
```

How can I apply Angular filter:

I have tried:

```
conData = JSON.stringify(data);
results = $filter('filter')(conData, filter, false);
```

I have also tried :

```
results = $filter('filter')(conData, filter, true);
results = $filter('filter')(conData, filter);
```

When I examine the results of the filter nothing changes and I get back the same array.

So if the filter applied was "Delivery"

The results array would be :
  [{"id":"compute-1.amazonaws.com_Delivery"}]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: A bit off-topic, is that `change` event inside a directive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it is a copy/paste mistake but the array you provide in your first source extract is wrong (or at least won't do what you expect). If you look closely the key id is repeated inside the same JSON object. Try with the following array :

```
[
 {"id":"compute-1.amazonaws.com_Delivery"},
 {"id":"compute-1.amazonaws.com_TaskJob"},
 {"id":"UpdateFiles"},
 {"id":"TaskRequest"}
];
```

BTW I assembled a lighter version of your code accessible [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/QAnqXH50t3zeS0XZrNKf?p=preview) where the filtering is working.

Comment: My mistake was applying JSON.stringify unnecessarily